# How to left or right justify a column header in a JTable

Tags: java, swing

I searched and couldn't find an answer for this.  By default column headers in a JTable are centered. How do I make certain column headers left or right justified instead?

TIA

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
TableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
table.getColumn(id).setHeaderRenderer(renderer);
```

Or, if you don't have the column names available:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(index).setHeaderRenderer(renderer);
```

Comment: I get an error because I don't seem to have an ID.
I use
table.getColumn(0).setHeaderRenderer(renderer);
for column 1

and 

table.getColumn(1).setHeaderRenderer(renderer);
for column 2

Comment: this works:
            table.getColumn(table.getColumnName(1)).setHeaderRenderer(renderer);

thanks

Comment: hey.why i get error on renderer.setHorizentalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT); says:can't find setHorizentalAlignment()...