# Multiple alignments in a single table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Well the question is simple.

How do I set a different alignment for two rows in te same table? I tried:

`table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(renderer)`

but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean different alignment for two `Columns`?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4103114/994125) might help you.

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that @GaborSch.

Comment: @Laf, that's the post where I got the idea to use table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(renderer), but it didn't work at all. It did nothing.

Comment: OK. I got it working with the code

table = new JTable(){
@Override
public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int col) {
DefaultTableCellRenderer leftRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
          leftRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
          rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
if (col == 0) return leftRenderer;
else return rightRenderer;
}
};

Now I only have to guess how to do the same with the header.

Comment: If you have the solution, please post it as an answer **properly formatted** :)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3157310/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. There's the code:

```
table = new JTable(){
    @Override
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int col) {
        DefaultTableCellRenderer leftRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        leftRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        // Return renderer for left aligned cells
        if (col == 0) return leftRenderer;
        // Return renderer for right aligned cells
        else return rightRenderer;
    }
};
```